# How do I achieve the following operation in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have three arrays:

```
tables = [{number:1},{number:2},{number:3},{number:4}];

foods = [
  {id:1, name:'Ice Cream'},
  {id:2, name:'Pizza'},
  {id:1, name:'Hot Dog'},
  {id:2, name:'Salad'}
];

orders = [
    {table_id: 2, food_id: 3},
    {table_id: 4, food_id: 2}
];
```

---

I want to:

1. List all tables by their number.
2. Check if the table have orders, i.e. table_id exists in `orders` array.
3. If it does, get the corresponding food_id from orders array and display the `food name`.

Something as follows:

---

```
<!-- !INCORRECT SYNTAX -->
<div *ngFor="let table of tables">
    <h1>TABLE #{{table.number}}</h1>

    <div *ngIf="orders && orders.length > 0 && orders.table_id.includes(table.number)">
        <ul *ngFor="let order of orders where(order.table_id == table.number)">
            <li>Orders: {{food_name_from(order.food_id) }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I just read that the new ECMAScript 2016 includes an [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method for arrays:

```
[1, 2, 3].includes(2);     // true
[1, 2, 3].includes(4);     // false
```

But I don't know how to implement it in my case with objects as elements. What would be the best approach to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `find` and `filter` instead `includes`.

Create a function that checks if the table has order:

```js
hasOrders(table_number){
    return this.orders.find((order) => order.table_id == table_number);
}
```

And use here:

```html
<div *ngIf="hasOrders(table.number)"> // *ngIf will check the length and return false if it is undefined or 0
```

After that, you need to grab all orders to display, you can create another function that get the orders like:

```js
getOrders(table_number){
    return this.orders.filter((order) => order.table_id == table_number);
}
```

And use here:

```html
<ul *ngFor="let order of getOrders(table.number)">
```

To get the food name:

```js
food_name_from(food_id){
    return (this.foods.find((food) => food.id == food_id)).name;
}
```

And use here:

```html
<li>Orders: {{food_name_from(order.food_id) }}</li>
```

This way you don't do useless process.

`Filter` will iterate over the array until the end and `find` will stop when the first occurrence is found. This is why we use two functions to check and grab the data.

Comment: That is breviloquent!